# What is this notation and why does it work in Chrome?

Tags: html, tags, custom-tag

I've just tried this:

```html
<style>
  rgraph:option {
    background: red;
    padding: 3px;
  }
</style>

<rgraph:option>canvas</rgraph:option>
```

And in Chrome (69.0.3497.100) it worked. But not IE 11 or Firefox.

And what is it? Obviously some new CSS feature that's implemented in Chrome only.

I do like the idea of being able to use custom tag names.

Comment: Whuuuut. Chrome doesn't interpret that ":option" as an unrecognized pseudo-class? Usually when working with pseudo-XML namespaces (i.e. not actual XHTML) you escape the colon in the selector with a backslash so it doesn't get treated as a pseudo-class symbol.

Comment: Does not work in my Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: @mplungjan: I wonder if including a copy of RGraph (of which Richard appears to be the author) might have any effect on things.

Comment: Interesting - I just tried a very basic HTML page on my desktop and it didn't work. Shucks.

Comment: And now I can't reproduce it at all. :-(

Comment: Though if I take out the colon and use a hyphen instead it works in Chrome, FF and IE11:<style>
    rgraph-docs-option {
        background-color: #f00;
        padding: 3px;
    }
</style>

<rgraph-docs-option>Foo</rgraph-docs-option>

Comment: I can confirm that